# Sorting Data from database

Tags: java, sorting

how to sort object in array list that contains :

```
ID   Name    price
1    aa      123
2    bb      100
3    cc      100
4    dd      300
5    ee      100
```

with price low to high

Comment: I didn'y downvote you, but you should really consider doing that sort in the database as it was designed to sort quickly.  What would be a one line query in SQL could take several dozen lines of Java code, and it would be slower than the database.

Comment: data above not from database. so I can't  use query to sort it.

Comment: @FrankyKuyz your question title states something different. But based on your comment your question is probably duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: For me, it was clear and I was going to post an answer!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY PRICE ASC
```

Comment: data above not from database. so I can't use query to sort it

Comment: ohooo, so would you show us where you get those data ( data source ), is from different table? or XML or..